# Giving weight to mysql search results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to improve my search functionality in one of my sites by ordering the records by those with the most matches.

I have the following mysql tables.

SurveyResponses

```
+--------+-------------+------------------+
| sID    |    Title    |  Description     |
+--------+-------------+------------------+
| 1      |  Set    1   | Some txt here    |
| 2      |  Set    2   | Other text here  |
+--------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answers:

```
+------+---------+------------+---------+
| aID  |  Parent |  Question  | Answer  |
+------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1    |  1      |      1     |  yes    | 
| 2    |  1      |      2     |  yes    |
| 3    |  1      |      3     |  yes    |
| 4    |  2      |      1     |  yes    |
| 5    |  2      |      2     |  no     |
| 6    |  2      |      3     |  no     |
+------+---------+------------+---------+
```

I want to get ALL the records from the SurveyResponses table and order them in order of the questions that were matched as correct in the answers table. The correct answers are as follows:

```
Q1 = yes
Q2 = no
Q3 = no
```

So based on this, the query should return Set 2 at the top of the results because the answers were all correct in the answers table for that question, whereas q2 and q3 were wrong in Set 1.

I imagine I need some kind of scoring system so I can do something like

```
IF q1 = yes THEN score = score + 1
```

Obviously I can do this in PHP, but not sure what method to use in mysql.

A answer to the question would be appreciated, but even a hint or link to the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The correct answers are as follows:" Isn't that something you'd want to store in the database!?!

Comment: I don't follow. The data is stored in the database - I just want to know how to order it! Are you suggesting an extra column to simply hold the 'score'?

Comment: "I don't follow." You and me both :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your design, or what you're trying to do so instead I'll offer up an alternative example that may or may not be helpful...

```
CREATE TABLE survey
(question_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,question VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,correct_answer VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO survey VALUES
(1,'Is Rome the capital of Italy?','Yes'),
(2,'Is Paris the capital of England?','No'),
(3,'Is London the capital of Spain?','No');

CREATE TABLE survey_response
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,question_id INT NOT NULL
,response VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,question_id)
);

INSERT INTO survey_response VALUES
(101,1,'Yes'),
(101,2,'Yes'),
(101,3,'Yes'),
(102,1,'Yes'),
(102,2,'No'),
(102,3,'No');

SELECT * FROM survey;
+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------+
| question_id | question                         | correct_answer |
+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------+
|           1 | Is Rome the capital of Italy?    | Yes            |
|           2 | Is Paris the capital of England? | No             |
|           3 | Is London the capital of Spain?  | No             |
+-------------+----------------------------------+----------------+

SELECT * FROM survey_response;
+---------+-------------+----------+
| user_id | question_id | response |
+---------+-------------+----------+
|     101 |           1 | Yes      |
|     101 |           2 | Yes      |
|     101 |           3 | Yes      |
|     102 |           1 | Yes      |
|     102 |           2 | No       |
|     102 |           3 | No       |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

So let's say I want to sort respondents (user_ids) according to who got the most correct answers. i could do that this way...

```
SELECT sr.user_id 
  FROM survey s 
  JOIN survey_response sr 
    ON sr.question_id = s.question_id 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(sr.response = s.correct_answer) DESC;
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|     102 |
|     101 |
+---------+
```